# How to permanently remove app from fabric account as its re-initializing with provided account once app starts?

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have integrated fabric crashlytics in one of my projects and right now I don't have a source of that project so that I have removed that app from my fabric account then also its reinitialized once any user installs that app in their phone.

So I just want to permanently remove that app from the account. Please let me know if you have any idea about this.

Comment: To confirm, you don't have the ability to change the API key / other code in the app?

Comment: No i don't have that code right now so how can i change the API key?

Comment: It would need to be done in the code. I'd suggest reaching out to Fabric support to try and stop the app from reappearing, since I was going to suggest transferring it to another organisation but this isn't possible without changing the code.